# What files need to be moved for Craft3 plugins?

Tags: craft3, plugins

I'm trying to get the redactor onto my site. I've successfully moved over plugins from the store and a custom plugin I created. But I did those towards the start and had migrated the entire project onto the site. I don't want to move 4,000 files over just to get one plugin to show up.

I've tried moving `composer.json`, `composer.lock`, and manually moving the specific vendor folder in as well. I also migrated the database from the dev site to the production site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're really close; `composer.json` is a list of packages and their [semvers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) that should be installed. `composer.lock` has a manifest of what is *actually* installed.

In order to deploy to production, you just need a step that executes `composer install` to install what is in the `composer.lock` file. Check out the [Deploying Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project#deploying-craft-cms) section of this article for a more thorough run-through.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question well. You can install Redactor editor directly from Plugin Store. After you can change files in vendor\craftcms\redactor\lib by some other Redactor version.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my issue is I can't install plugins on my site in production so I have to do it in my dev environment. I'd like to be able to install the plugin and then move only the files that need to be moved.

Comment: I think the best way is install plugin by composer, see section Installation with composer here: https://github.com/craftcms/redactor You can do it without Plugins Store. All files of redactor plugin are in two directiries config\redactor and vendor\craftcms\redactor.

Comment: The issue isn't installing the plugin, it's moving it over to my production environment without moving over every single file.

Comment: Sorry, you need "install" your plugin manually without composer. The source of information can be Yii2, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer#